# VBA KeyDown Event Assigned to ActiveX Control through Class Module Not Working

Tags: excel, vba

Aim: To assign a keydown event to 4 TextBoxes on Worksheet (Sheet1) via Class Module

I have an Excel Worksheet (Sheet1) that has 4 TextBoxes on it (default names - TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4).

Steps Taken:

(1) Created a class module named ClsEventTxtBx with following codes.

```
    Public WithEvents CTxtBx As MSForms.TextBox

      Private Sub CTxtBx_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then Debug.Print CTxtBx.Name
      End Sub
```

(2) Added the following codes in the Workbook Open event.

```
    Dim TxtBxArr() As New ClsEventTxtBx
 
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
      Dim i As Integer, shp As Shape

      For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            If TypeName(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "TextBox" Then
                i = i + 1
                ReDim TxtBxArr(1 To i)
                Set TxtBxArr(i).CTxtBx = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
            End If
        End If
      Next shp
    
    End Sub
```

Could you please find what is wrong with the code?

Comment: You need to use `Redim Preserve` if you want to maintain the existing array content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim TxtBxArr() As New ClsEventTxtBx
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Dim i As Integer, shp As OLEObject

    For Each shp In Sheet1.OLEObjects
          If shp.progID = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then
              i = i + 1
              ReDim Preserve TxtBxArr(1 To i)
              shp.Name = "myshp" & i
              Set TxtBxArr(i).CTxtBx = shp.Object
          End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```